# Code is working fine in my system but coursera autograder is giving me unknown signal

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, binary-search, coursera-api

**Task** -- The goal in this code problem is to implement the binary search algorithm.

**Input Format** -- The first line of the input contains an integer n and a sequence a0 < a1 < ... < an−1 of n pairwise distinct positive integers in increasing order. The next line contains an integer k and k positive integers b0,b1,...,bk−1.

**Constraints** -- 1 ≤ n,k ≤ 10^4; 1 ≤ a[i] ≤ 10^9 for all 0 ≤ i < n; 1 ≤ b[]j ≤ 10^9 for all 0 ≤ j < k;

**Output Format** -- For all i from 0 to k−1, output an index 0 ≤ j ≤ n−1 such that aj = bi or −1 if there is no such index.

I am using code blocks with c++11 compiler.
I have already tried stress testing and got correct results in my system.
But coursera autograder is giving me unknown signal 11.
In some problems it gives unknown signal 8.
Can anyone tell me the possible reason behind this.

```
int binary_search(const vector<long long> &a, long long x) {
  size_t left = 0, right = (size_t)a.size()-1;
  size_t mid = 0;
  while(left<=right){
    mid = (left+right)/2;
    if(x < a[mid]){
        right = mid-1;
    }
    else if(x > a[mid]){
        left = mid+1;
    }
    else return mid;
  }
  return -1;
}
int main() {
  size_t n;
  std::cin >> n;
  vector<long long> a(n);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    std::cin >> a[i];
  }
  size_t m;
  std::cin >> m;
  vector<long long> b(m);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    std::cin >> b[i];
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
    //replace with the call to binary_search when implemented
    std::cout << binary_search(a, b[i]) << ' ';
  }
}
```

Actual result that i got in autograder.

```
Failed case #4/36: unknown signal 11 (Time used: 0.00/1.00, memory used: 40071168/536870912.)
```

Comment: Not related I guess, but why are you using *long long* for values less than 109?

Comment: Maybe you meant 10^9 ?

Comment: Not related but just curious, which course it is?

Comment: Even 10⁹ will fit in plain old `int` (it is running on at least 32-bit platform). 2¹⁰ ≅ 10³, so 10⁹ ≅ 2³⁰ and `int` on 32-or-more-bit platform can hold -2³¹ … 2³¹-1.

Comment: @JuniverHazoic **Algorithmic Toolbox
by University of California San Diego & National Research University Higher School of Economics**

Comment: What happens if your input is empty?

Comment: Prakirti, it is a violation of Coursera's Honor Code to post your solutions publicly. Please redact out some parts of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the vector has e.g. size 2, then you initialize `left = 0`, `right = 1` and `mid = 0`. `left <= right` so you calculate `mid = 0` and check if `x < a[0]`. **If that happens, you now set `right = -1`**. In unsigned arithmetic, that is a really large number. Your loop continues because `0 <= really large number`, you calculate `mid = half of really large number` and access the vector there. That's **UB** and gets your program killed.

Switching to signed types means `right = -1` is indeed smaller than `left = 0` and terminates the loop.

Comment: Actually, that happens if `x < a[0]` for any size of the vector, because `right` will be decreasing until it gets to this.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about Coursera test cases, but your code will definitely fail with two edge cases:

1) empty input vector `a` -> you'll get underflow in line `right = (size_t)a.size()-1;`. In other words, `right` will become a large positive value, you'll enter in the loop and try to retrieve `a[mid]` where `mid` will be some large positive index. Of course, trying to get this from an empty array would result with an error.

2) `left+right` too large -> overflow -> bug found in many binary search implementations, even in books :) Use instead `mid = (right - left) / 2 + left`;

Comment: In **Constaints** paragraph, OP provides some information on the test cases

Comment: @Damien you are right, those two edge cases shouldn't occur in this test suite then.

Comment: In input format, it is already mentioned `1 <= n,k <= 10^4`. So I don't think this may be the problem, but 2nd one sounds correct.

Comment: @PrakirtiLakhotiya Please correct your question, put `10^4` instead of `104`, and `10^9` instead of `109`.

Comment: @MiljenMikic I have tried both the possible changes that you have suggested. Still getting same error. Maybe there are some memory leaks or something which i am not able to figure out.

Comment: @PrakirtiLakhotiya The code you show has no memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

By changing all `size_t` to `long`, it works correctly.
The **unknown signal 11** means **segmentation fault**, i.e. something is wrong with memory access.
So changing  all `size_t` to `long` increase the range of `vector` and hence letting in fit more values which fixes the memory access problem.

Comment: cppreference: *std::size_t can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array).* I don't understand what happens!

Comment: @Damien With this added information the reason is pretty clear: Some `size_t` value is supposed to be negative at some point (but instead is a huge positive value due to unsigned wraparound). There are only two places in the program where that can happen.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Clear indeed now. Good answer also. I remenber now a recommendation of Bjarne Stroustrup that unsigned int should be avoided when operations are performed on it.